# Excel 2010 - Remove characters from a cell, number of characters varies

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list exported from another application. The results are returned with extra characters between them.

What I get:

```
Mary One;#123;#Bob Two;#2345;#Charles Three;#445
```

What I want:

```
Mary One; Bob Two; Charles Three
```

The number of users which could be listed in the cell is not consistent. The further complicating factor is that the numbers vary between 3 and 4 characters.

I'm trying to keep this from getting very complicated. Ideally, this would be a formula I'd communicate to the rest of my department to use as needed.

I'm going to be using SUBSTITUTE and LEN, but I could use some help keeping this clean.

Comment: MUST it be a formula?  Creating a User Defined Function using RegEx would be an easy way to deal with the problem.  Though, distributing the UDF might pose difficulties.

Comment: Do you want the answer in one cell or across  multiple cells? (Ie. A1= long string, B1="Mary One;", C1="Bob two;", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to present here couple of options to choose from but all of them rely on regular expressions. It is possible not to use regex but I think it might involve a bit more time.

**[Option 1 - https://regex101.com/]**
Visit page https://regex101.com/
Set flavor to ‘pcre (php)’ - it is the default option
Regular expression:  `(?<=;)(#\d+;#)|(;#\d+$)` Flag: `g`
Test string: `Mary One;#123;#Bob Two;#2345;#Charles Three;#445`
Substitution:  // one space (or it can be left blank) 
Output: `Mary One; Bob Two; Charles Three`
The output needs to be trimmed as there is one additional space at the end.

**[Option 2 - LibreOffice Calc (portable)]**
Calc 'Find & Replace' window allows using regular expressions.
Ctrl+H
Find: `(?<=;)(#\d+;#)|(;#\d+$)`
Replace with: one space or blank
In section 'Other options' check 'Regular expressions'
Click on 'Replace All' button.

**[Option 3 - Notepad++]**
I am mentioning N++ here as it is really powerful tool while working with many types of texts. Its power sits largely in numerous plugins. 
But here I will refer to a standard Replace window. Regex allows splitting the matched parts of text. It is called grouping. Each group can have a name and that name can be used in the replacement.
Ctrl+H → Replace tab
Wrap around: checked
Search Mode: Regular expression
Find what: `(?'name_surname'[^;#]+\s[^;#]+;)(#\d+(;#|$))`
Replace with: `$+{name_surname}`
Click on button ‘Replace All’

Meaning:
‘Find what’ finds everything – the wanted and unwanted text.
‘Replace with’ replaces the raw text with only wanted parts.

**[Option 4 - Excel – user defined function (VBA)]**

Open Visual Basic editor (Alt+F11) 
Add reference:
Tools --> References --> Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

```
Option Explicit
Function leaveNames(CellValue As Variant)
    Dim RegEx As RegExp
    Dim Expr As String
    Set RegEx = New RegExp
    Expr = "(#\d+;#)|(;#\d+$)"
    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.IgnoreCase = False
    RegEx.MultiLine = False
    RegEx.Pattern = Expr
    leaveNames = RegEx.Replace(CellValue, "")
End Function
```

**[Summary]**
I tried to focus on rather quick but fully functional solutions so I guess sth can be taken from it.

Comment: Option 4 has proven to be exactly what my users need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately, I just ran it on a new report, and it breaks if there are more than 2 names. In the cell with a third name I got: Tom Kent;Julie Y Busse;#562;DeNae Leverentz

Comment: I think that the key difference between the string from the question and the comment is that in the latter not all names start with the hash. I’ve modified the regular expression by adding a question mark which makes the hash optional:  `Expr = "(#\d+;#?)|(;#\d+$)"`. The new expression still works with the previous strings. If you found some more negative scenarios then most probably the root cause will sit in regex but fortunately this can easily be changed.

Comment: Thank you! I have not found any other negative scenarios!

Answer (score 0):

I attempted the formula.  It wasn't pretty.  Though, I'm sure there are other ways to do this.

This formula will take your string in Cell A1 and remove the `#123` and `#2345` strings.  You can always expand the technique further if you wish.  It finds the occurrences of "#" then breaks the string down to smaller pieces.

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("#",A1,1)-1) &  MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("#",A1,1)),SEARCH("#",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("#",A1,1)),1)+1,SEARCH("#",MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("#",A1,1)),SEARCH("#",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("#",A1,1)),1)+1,LEN((A1))),1)-1)
```

It's neither clean nor easily communicable.

I suggest a User Defined Function.  [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) is an article explaining how to set up and distribute a user function.  Give the UDF a go and if you have questions regarding the process, please ask.