# EXCEL - How to delete every word that contains @

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know about some function like substitute or ctrl + F,

but now, I have problems with the sentences that contains @yoyo, @yihaa, @hohoho etc.

Maybe you can help, how to delete them, not just "@" but 1 package, the word too.

Comment: You mean to say delete all words starts with '@' from sentence !!

Comment: yes, all words!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods, one is Worksheet function and second is Macro.*

**Method 1:**

[image]

- Formula in cell `H27` and fill down.

  ```
  =TRIM(LEFT(G27,FIND("@",G27)-1))&RIGHT(G27,LEN(G27)-FIND(" ",G27,FIND("@",G27))+1)
  ```

---

**Method 2:**

**:Caveat:**

*This is an optional part since it deletes only the special character from sentence.*

- To open VBA editor press **Alt+F11**.
- Hit **I**nsert TAB & hit **M**odule.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code.
- Press **Alt+Q** to return to Sheet.
- **S**ave the file as **M**acro Enabled.

  ```
  Function REMOVETEXTS(strInput As String, rngFind As Range) As String

  Dim strTemp As String
  Dim strFind As String

  strTemp = strInput

   For Each cell In rngFind
   strFind = cell.Value
   strTemp = Replace(strTemp, strFind, "")
   Next cell

   REMOVETEXTS = strTemp

   End Function
  ```

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- Put special characters in Column `H`.
- Formula in cell `I38` & fill it down.

  `=REMOVETEXTS(G38,H$38:H$42)`

**N.B.**

- *This Macro is better & versatile also, since it deletes special character from more than one word (`check G38` ) as well as works with any special characters.*

Comment: Thank you @Rajesh S. this function and the logic is very helpful

Comment: Glad to help U @Damar TD ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

As stated, a solution using pure Excel will need to use a VBA function.
The following post can get you started:
[Excel 2010 - Remove characters from a cell, number of characters varies](https://superuser.com/questions/1163435/excel-2010-remove-characters-from-a-cell-number-of-characters-varies).

However, it will be much easier exporting the spreadsheet as a CSV file
and using an evolved text editor to remove the words,
then re-import the file into Excel.

For example, using Notepad++, use the following Regex to remove the words.
You may add a character (such as space) at the end of the find term to also
remove it when following the word.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @harrymc, this method is nice too, it's good for 1 character and word, in many many rows :)